# Count number of rows matching a criteria

Tags: r

I am looking for a command in R which is equivalent of this SQL statement. I want this to be a very simple basic solution without using complex functions OR dplyr type of packages.

```
Select count(*) as number_of_states 
  from myTable
where  sCode = "CA"
```

so essentially I would be counting number of rows matching my where condition.

I have imported a csv file into mydata as a data frame.So far I have tried these with no avail.

1. `nrow(mydata$sCode == "CA")  ## ==>> returns NULL`
2. `sum(mydata[mydata$sCode == 'CA',], na.rm=T) ## ==>> gives Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`
3. `sum(subset(mydata, sCode='CA', select=c(sCode)), na.rm=T) ## ==>> FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`
4. `sum(mydata$sCode == "CA", na.rm=T)  ## ==>> returns count of all rows in the entire data set, which is not the correct result.`

and some variations of the above samples. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: sum(mydata$sCode == "CA") should work. We can't help any more without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I would of thought option 4 would work. ex. `dat <- data.frame(x=c("a", "b", NA)) ; sum(dat$x=="a", na.rm=T)`

Comment: The use of "NROW" (capital letters) works for a vector, but it can be misleading and should be avoided in proper coding.

Comment: @SteveKern: are you asking for sample data?

Comment: @user20650: Could you please clarify? what does x represent in your statement - data.frame(x=c("a", "b", NA)) ;  ? I presume c is required per syntax, "a" and "b" are state codes like "CA" and "WA"?

Comment: Hi @multi-sam; yes, i just used a short variable name when creating some dummy data:  `dat` is `mydata`, `dat$x` is `mydata$sCode`, and `"a"` represents `"CA"`

Answer (score 57):

`mydata$sCode == "CA"` will return a boolean array, with a `TRUE` value everywhere that the condition is met. To illustrate:

```
> mydata = data.frame(sCode = c("CA", "CA", "AC"))
> mydata$sCode == "CA"
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

There are a couple of ways to deal with this:

1. `sum(mydata$sCode == "CA")`, as suggested in the comments; because
   `TRUE` is interpreted as 1 and `FALSE` as 0, this should return the
   numer of `TRUE` values in your vector.
2. `length(which(mydata$sCode == "CA"))`; the `which()` function
   returns a vector of the indices where the condition is met, the
   length of which is the count of `"CA"`.

Edit to expand upon what's happening in #2:

```
> which(mydata$sCode == "CA")
[1] 1 2
```

`which()` returns a vector identify each column where the condition is met (in this case, columns 1 and 2 of the dataframe). The `length()` of this vector is the number of occurences.

Comment: @mult-sam, do you mean that the second suggestion I provided (`length(which(mydata$sCode == "CA"))`) doesn't work for you? Without access to your data I'm not sure why that would be- using the simple example dataframe provided in my answer that code functions properly.

Comment: yes its not giving me the correct result. the length statement above is retuning the count of all the rows in the DF, not the correct result.

Comment: @multi-sam you need to provide a reproducible example. The solution here works on example data sets. If it's not working on your data, you need to provide your data and prove this.

Comment: solution #2  work for me! Thanks @Joe! @multi-sam, you sure that not all the observations in the DF are from California?? :P Thanks for the question BTW.

Answer (score 29):

`sum` is used to add elements; `nrow` is used to count the number of rows in a rectangular array (typically a matrix or data.frame); `length` is used to count the number of elements in a vector. You need to apply these functions correctly.

Let's assume your data is a data frame named "dat". Correct solutions:

```
nrow(dat[dat$sCode == "CA",])
length(dat$sCode[dat$sCode == "CA"])
sum(dat$sCode == "CA")
```

Comment: all these are the ones I have already tried, returning count of all the rows in DF, not a correct result.

Comment: @multi-sam -- that's not possible. Show your code. 
Here is an example on the cars data:
`data(cars); str(cars)`
`data.frame': 50 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ speed: num  4 4 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ...
 $ dist : num  2 10 4 22 16 10 18 26 34 17 ...`
> nrow(cars[cars$speed == 4,])
[1] 2
> length(cars$speed[cars$speed == 4])
[1] 2

Comment: @multi-sam you need to provide a reproducible example. The solution here works on example data sets. If it's not working on your data, you need to provide your data and prove this.

Comment: None of these work, getting 34336 when there are only 654 rows.

Answer (score 7):

1. `mydata$sCode` is a vector, it's why nrow output is NULL.
2. `mydata[mydata$sCode == 'CA',]` returns `data.frame` where `sCode == 'CA'`. sCode includes character. That's why `sum` gives you the error.
3. `subset(mydata, sCode='CA', select=c(sCode))`, you should use `sCode=='CA'` instead `sCode='CA'`. Then subset returns you vector where sCode equals CA, so you should use

   length(subset(na.omit(mydata), sCode='CA', select=c(sCode)))

Or you can try this: `sum(na.omit(mydata$sCode) == "CA")`

Comment: same thing as above. returns the count of all of the rows in DF.

Comment: What exactly did you try this one length(subset(na.omit(mydata), sCode='CA', select=c(sCode)))  or this sum(na.omit(mydata$sCode) == "CA")?

Comment: Hi, I tried both; the first one returns a count of 1 and the second one returns the count of all the rows; both are incorrect results.

Comment: Could you please provide your example data set? Because it works on mine.

Answer (score 5):

With `dplyr` package, Use

```
 nrow(filter(mydata, sCode == "CA")),
```

All the solutions provided here gave me same error as multi-sam but that one worked.

Answer (score 4):

Just give a try using subset

```
nrow(subset(data,condition))
```

Example

```
nrow(subset(myData,sCode == "CA"))
```

Answer (score 3):

to get the number of observations the number of rows from your Dataset would be more valid:

```
nrow(dat[dat$sCode == "CA",])
```

Answer (score 2):

grep command can be used

> CA = mydata[grep("CA", mydata$sCode, ]
>
> nrow(CA)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: CA = mydata[grep("CA", mydata$sCode), ]       This command will create a data frame "CA" which only consists of rows containing characters CA.        and nrow() wil return no of such coloumns

Answer (score 1):

Call `nrow` passing as argument the name of the dataset:

```
nrow(dataset)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this short function to make it easier using `dplyr`:

```
countc <- function(.data, ..., preserve = FALSE){
   return(nrow(filter(.data, ..., .preserve = preserve)))
}
```

With this you can just use it like `filter`. For example:

```
countc(data, active == TRUE)
[1] 42
```