# Count variables in data frame depending on other variable

Tags: r

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195996/count-number-of-rows-matching-a-criteria/28196342#28196342) but I have not a constant criteria.

My data frame looks like this:

```
> head(df)
  id run corr rank
1  a  v1  0.2    1
2  a  v2  0.3    2
3  a  v3  0.6    3
4  b  v2  0.1    1
5  b  v1  0.3    2
6  b  v3  0.4    3

> dput(df)
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), 
    run = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L), .Label = c(" v1", " v2", " v3"), class = "factor"), 
    corr = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.4, 0.7), rank = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "run", "corr", "rank"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Now, I want to count how often v1  (respectively v2 and v3) is equal to rank 1 (respectively 2 and 3). The output should look like this:

```
    1   2   3
v1  2   2   0
v2  2   2   0
v3  0   0   4
```

Comment: I wonder how many times this question has been asked before? Did you do any searching?

Comment: @BondedDust, sometimes you just don't know what's the right keywords to look for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `table`:

```
table(df$run, df$rank)

      1 2 3
   v1 2 2 0
   v2 2 2 0
   v3 0 0 4
```

Answer (score 3):

The `dplyr` and `tidyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  count(run, rank) %>%
  spread(rank, n, fill = 0)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# 
#      run     1     2     3
#   (fctr) (int) (int) (int)
# 1     v1     2     2     0
# 2     v2     2     2     0
# 3     v3     0     0     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `table`

```
> table(df[, c("run", "rank")])
     rank
run   1 2 3
   v1 2 2 0
   v2 2 2 0
   v3 0 0 4
```