# R language count rows of dataframe matching a criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataframe population with Height and Weight

```
    Height    Weight
1   1.4349813 53.73766
2   1.6875582 61.83858
3   1.4952729 51.64203
etc....
```

How can I count how many of these people have a height higher than 1.70 and a weight higher than 60?

```
I tried nrow(which(population$Height > 1.70 && population$Weight > 60))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of rows matching a criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195996/count-number-of-rows-matching-a-criteria)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R:

```
nrow(population[population$Height > 1.70 & population$Weight > 60, ])
```

With dpylr:

```
library(dpylr)

population %>% filter(Height > 1.70 & Weight > 60) %>% nrow()
```

Comment: `dpylr` imports `%>%` from `magrittr` so you don't need to load `magrittr` again.

Answer (score 1):

You could proceed as follows:

```
sum(population$Height > 1.70 & population$Weight > 60)
```