# Sorting data in an imported table in R by multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have imported a data set into R studio and want to count the rows that have certain values in multiple columns. The columns I want to sort by are titled "ROW" which I want less than or equal to 90, "house" which I want equal to 1 and "type" which I want equal to 1.

I know that I can use the sum command like this:

```
sum(data$type==1)
```

and that returns the rows with the value 1 in the "type" column. I have tried to combine these functions like this:

```
with(data, sum((type==1),(ROW<=90),(house==1))
```

to no avail.

Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Probably you need this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195996/count-number-of-rows-matching-a-criteria .

Answer (score 0):

If we need to combine logical expressions, use `&` (if all of the conditions return TRUE) or `|` (if any of the conditions return TRUE)

```
with(data, sum((type==1)&(ROW<=90)&(house==1)))
```