# Count Records Equal to Max in Data.Table within group

Tags: r, data.table

I want to count how many rows are equal to the max value within a group (in data.table).  I know from [Select the row with the maximum value in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group) how to find the max value in data.table.

```
set.seed(5)
z <- data.table( data.frame(
    group=( sample( letters[1:5], 25,  replace=T) ),
    size=( sample( 1:5, 25,  replace=T) )))

z <- z[ order( group, size ), ]

z[ , maxsize := max(size), by = .(group)]
```

So in this example, I want a column equal to 2 for group a, (since there are two observations equal to 3) and 4 for b, 2 for c etc.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Count number of rows matching a criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195996/count-number-of-rows-matching-a-criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a logical vector is summed the TRUE/FALSE values will be regarded as 1/0 so sum `size == max(size)` by group.

```
z[, count_max := sum(size == max(size)), by = group]
```

Alternately, in base R we could use `ave`

```
transform(z, count_max = ave(size, group, FUN = \(x) sum(x == max(x))))
```